# Reactjs how to disable all DOM elements and place text on top

Tags: css, reactjs, spinner

I want to have a spinner on the top layer of my application during an AJAX request. The spinner will disable the mouse interaction with the DOM. I have created the following codepen which resembles the issue I am running on. Jsx looks like this:

```
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h1>Hello, React and ES6!</h1>
        <p>Let's play. :)</p>
        <OverLay />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

const OverLay = ({loading}) => {
  return (
    <div className="load">
      <div id="top">
        Hello world!
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("app"));
```

And css:

```
.load { 
  opacity: 0.6;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  background-color: #000;
  z-index: 30;
  pointer-events: none;
}

#top {
  position: absolute;
  left:50%;
  top:50%;
  z-index: 31;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

[Codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/vdYryY?editors=0110)

Comment: What exactly is the issue you're having?

Comment: @treyhakanson In the codepen that I 've posted the 'Hello world' text does not appear at all.